# What is causing syslog to log lots of "Dial failed: dial tcp x.x.x.x:port: connection refused" messages?

Tags: kubernetes

All of the nodes in our AWS kubernetes cluster (Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6", GitCommit:"388061f00f0d9e4d641f9ed4971c775e1654579d", GitTreeState:"clean"}) are getting the following messages sent to /var/log/syslog which are filling the disk very quickly (32GB in about 24 hours).

```
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: I1204 03:13:36.961584   15171 proxysocket.go:130] Accepted TCP connection from 172.30.0.164:58063 to 172.30.0.39:33570
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.961775   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.0.7:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.961888   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.2.9:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.962104   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.0.7:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.962275   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.2.9:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.962299   15171 proxysocket.go:133] Failed to connect to balancer: failed to connect to an endpoint.
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: I1204 03:13:36.962380   15171 proxysocket.go:130] Accepted TCP connection from 172.30.0.87:29540 to 172.30.0.39:33570
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.962630   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.0.7:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.962746   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.2.9:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.962958   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.0.7:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.963084   15171 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.244.2.9:5000: connection refused
Dec  4 03:13:36 ubuntu kube-proxy[15171]: E1204 03:13:36.963105   15171 proxysocket.go:133] Failed to connect to balancer: failed to connect to an endpoint.
```

We created the cluster using `export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash` if that is relevant.

Can anyone point me into the right direction as to the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

port 5000 is used by the local docker registry usually.
It is an add-on though. 
Is your cluster pulling images from that local registry? If so, is it working? how is it setup?

this link may help figure your config issues:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/registry

Comment: Thanks.  We rebuilt the cluster to the 1.1 version which doesn't seem to have this problem so I don't know if we'll be able to figure out what happened here but your answer makes sense.

Comment: Accepting your answer as it was the only plausible answer given.